How to get the size of raw logs ingested into Elastic?
I want to determine the size of raw logs ingested into Elastic. Is it possible to do this directly in Elastic, or are there any third-party tools that can help? Any ideas on how to achieve this?
Currently, we have a setup to determine the size of indices using the Cat API. However, this only provides the index size, which can differ significantly from the size of the raw logs.

You can leverage the Mapper size plugin, which will create a _size field containing the raw size of the _source document that you can then sum up.

I'm already familiar with this plugin. I believe it provides the size of the document after ingestion, rather than the raw log size before it is converted to the ELK-specific format. What I need is the raw log size prior to its conversion by ELK.

Not according to this test, we can see that _size is supposed to contain source.length()

TLDR;
There are multiple ways to achieve this. I depends a bit what you goal is.
Get the size of each document
I believe the solution proposed by @Val is the easiest. The mapper size plug-in should give you the actual size per documents of the _source field. Which is the raw document ingested by elasticsearch.

The mapper-size plugin provides the _size metadata field which, when enabled, indexes the size in bytes of the original _source field.

Get the size of the log (before being parsed into json)
This might be addressed in an ingest pipeline or which ever tool you use to read logs from.
Those tools most like have a processor you could leverage to get the size and provide it to elasticsearch.
Getting the global size on elasticsearch
I believe you could also use the _disk_usage api.  You should find in the response the size on disk taken by the _source field.
